# border-bottom for all list items (connection), how will it work?

Tags: html, css

I created an unsorted list with list items. It looks like this:

```
<ul id="mylist">
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="[[Array]]" />
  <label for="[[Array]]"><img src="images/[[ArrayImage]]"/></label>
  <div class="subtitle">[[Name]]</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

So it looks like one the picture I've added. The picture name is at the bottom of the image but if I enter "border-bottom" in CSS it shows only a border at the images. Is there a way to show a border which is connected together (like on the picture)? I hope anyone can help me. Thanks

[image: How it looks and should look]

Comment: Can you share a working example, with the CSS aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish you use code snippet to better human understanding. I will change some of your codes and add some `CSS` codes:

```css
#my-list {
  display: flex;
}

#my-list input {
  display: none;
}

#my-list input:checked ~ .subtitle {
  border-color: red;
}

#my-list input:checked ~ img {
  border-color: red;
}

#my-list li {
  width: 25%;
  list-style: none;
}

#my-list li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

#my-list li label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#my-list li img {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#my-list li .subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <img src="https://medicoads.ir/imgs/car1.jpg"/>
      <span class="subtitle">car-1</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <img src="https://medicoads.ir/imgs/car2.jpg"/>
      <span class="subtitle">car-2</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <img src="https://medicoads.ir/imgs/car3.jpg"/>
      <span class="subtitle">car-3</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <img src="https://medicoads.ir/imgs/car4.jpg"/>
      <span class="subtitle">car-4</span>
    </label>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your fast answer. This is how my code actually looks like. Is there a way to connect the bottom-border of this 4 items? So that it is a constant solid line?

Comment: @userprogrammer123, you're welcome, I do not understand what do you mean by `connect`? if you mean how it works by click? I write `input` inside of `label` so all of them now have actions.

Comment: @userprogrammer123, please click on each image or its subtitle. you can see the borders turn to red line.

Comment: oh sorry that was my mistake. I accidentally changed the correct order. The upper picture should show how it actually looks and the other how it should look. I'm really sorry for that. Do you understand it now?

Comment: @userprogrammer123, no, I don't.

Comment: I updated the picture in my question. I hope you understand what I mean. I can't explain it very well because my english isnt the best

Comment: @userprogrammer123, I updated the code, please run the snippet and see, if it is write please help me. thanks.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

A DIV has it's display set to block by default, meaning that you take up the width of the parent element. Because the li has no fixed width, the div takes up the full width available to it. If you set it's style to border bottom, it will apply it to this same full width meaning you get a full line.

There are two possible solutions to this, I've provided a working example (you can click Run Code Snippet below to view the code in action).

```html
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="[[Array]]" />
    <label for="[[Array]]"><img src="images/[[ArrayImage]]"/></label><br>
    <span style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey;" class="subtitle">[[Name]]</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="mylist2">
  <li>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="[[Array]]" />
      <label for="[[Array]]"><img src="images/[[ArrayImage]]"/></label>
    </div>
    <span style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey;" class="subtitle">[[Name]]</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In one, we're simply changing the subtitle div to a span, which has inline-block display as default, and then we're adding an additional < br > tag to split it up.

In the second, we simply encase everything BUT the subtitle in an additional div. This will achieve the same effect.